# How to pass object to jButton1ActionPerformed

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

I am making GUI in NetBeans using JFrame, Now I want to show some data from an existing object when a button is clicked.but the problem is that I can't pass an object to jButton1ActionPerformed as I can't edit this function and I don't want to create static function.Thanks

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
   System.out.println(Class.getdata());//here i want to access getdata 
   //function without creating an object here.HOw to pass an object here?
}
```

Comment: Make the data object variable Class Global.

Comment: I don't want to make it global as well.thanks

Comment: Generally speaking, you can't.  When the `ActionListener` is triggered, you need to  determine which action was triggered and then take appropriate action.  "How" you do this comes a lot down to how you've designed your code.  A "simple" solution would be to have the data available as an instance field of the parent class. Having said all that, I would recommend avoiding form editors, they dictate, in many case, inflexible design requirements